# What is the DN value to add Windows Active Directory attributes / ObjectClasses to OpenLDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am newbie in `LDAP` and trying to add extra `attribute`s & `ObjectClass` to `OpenLDAP` (2.4.40) schema, so it could compatible with the java code that is working with Active Directory

I did quite a lot of research online and finally come to this `.ldif` file, but can't quite figure out what is the `dn` that I should put in there for the target schema. The `cn=ldapadm,dc=myapp,dc=local` is the `DN` I created for current project, but I guess that shouldn't be the place to whole these global `attributes` and `objectclasses`

```
dn: cn=ldapadm,dc=myapp,dc=local
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: cn=ldapadm,dc=myapp,dc=local
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221 NAME 'sAMAccountName' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 1.2.840.113556.1.2.210 NAME 'proxyAddresses' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.750 NAME 'groupType' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 1.3.114.7.4.2.0.33 NAME 'memberOf' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 1.2.840.113556.1.5.9 NAME 'user' DESC 'a user' SUP organizationalPerson STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( userPassword $ memberOf ) )
olcObjectClasses: {1}( 1.2.840.113556.1.5.8 NAME 'group' DESC 'a group of users' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( groupType $ cn ) MAY member )
```

The error

```
adding new entry "cn=ldapadm,dc=myapp,dc=local"
ldap_add: Already exists (68)
```

and if I use a dummy `dn`

```
dn: cn=config
```

the error becomes

```
adding new entry "cn=config"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
    additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

So how should I define the `dn` so I can register the `Active Directory` elements into global setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DN of the user you're loggin in as is `cn=ldapadm,dc=myapp,dc=local`.

The DN of the entire configuration subtree is `cn=config`.

The DN of the schema is `cn=schema,cn=config`.

Comment: Thanks, so sounds like `cn=schema,cn=config` should be the dn to register the attribute / objectClass?

Comment: Yep, I changed `dn` to `cn=schema,cn=config` and it works, Thanks !